# Running Eclipse aplication or applet with permissions

Tags: java, eclipse, permissions, applet

I have applet which I run in command line like this:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_21\bin\appletviewer.exe" -J"-Djava.security.policy=java.policy.applet" cw11.html
```

How can I run this applet in Eclipse with my `java.policy.applet` permissions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its a long time since I wrote an applet, but you should be able to do it by creating a new applet run configuration.

1. Choose the Run -> Run Configurations menu.
2. Right click "Java Applet" and choose "New".
3. Give your run configuration a name.
4. Select your project and the applet class.
5. Choose the "arguments" tab and enter your security policy VM argument.
6. Click "Run" and off you go.